# Border in the middle only?

Tags: html, css, border

Is this possible to do in CSS? I tried everything that I know about.

[image: Is this possible to do in CSS?]

Comment: What HTML and CSS are you using? Can you provide a snippet (The `<>` icon in the question editor)?

Comment: This could be achieved rather easily by separating the two content blocks and giving the one on the left a `border-right`

Comment: Hi, welcom to StackOverflow. In order for your question to be well recieved, you need to tell us what have you tried. If possible, also supply us with clear and concise example of code you have and that illustrate your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to do this only with `border-right` or `border-left`. I can't think of a way the CSS can know in advance if the border will be exclusively on the inside of a table.

For this, I would suggest choose some approaches:

- Make a class for the rightmost column only, with a `border-left` property
- Make a class for the leftmost column only, with a `border-right` property
- Make a class for all the center columns (if more than one), with both `border-left` and `border-right`.